# Cannot access Ubuntu shared folder from Windows 10 host (VirtualBox)

Tags: networking, server, permissions, virtualbox, samba

I have asked a similar question in another post, but the situation has changed so much that I think it deserves another post.

I am running Ubuntu 19.04 on VirtualBox with a Windows 10 host. I have successfully shared my Windows folder with Ubuntu, but I am struggling to do the share the other way around.

After lots of fiddling, including running `service smbd start`, I have shared the Ubuntu folder I'd like Windows to be able to see. Windows cannot see this folder; nor the entire Ubuntu machine in fact.

I have installed Samba on Ubuntu and have configured `smb.conf` like this (extract):

```
#
# Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# We want Samba to only log to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd}.
# Append syslog@1 if you want important messages to be sent to syslog too.
   logging = file

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone server" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap config * :              backend = tdb
;   idmap config * :              range   = 3000-7999
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : backend = tdb
;   idmap config YOURDOMAINHERE : range   = 100000-999999
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 means that usershare is disabled.
#   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

# Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
# to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
# user’s home directory as \\server\username
[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = yes

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server. Un-comment the following parameter
# to make sure that only “username” can connect to \\server\username
valid users = %S

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change next
# parameter to ‘yes’ if you want to be able to write to them.
writable = yes 
# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
# can connect to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

I don't know if there's any further configuration I need to do in Ubuntu, and I have no idea how to configure Windows to be able to see this folder. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you created a user on Ubuntu, with permissions to access Samba?

Comment: I have created a user for myself, but I don't know how to give that user access to samba.

Comment: The command is `smbpasswd -a <username>` - replace username with your name, of course.  It will then prompt you for a password to use when accessing the system via Samba. Could you post the entirety of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`  ?  There are a couple of additional parameters that would like to check for you.

Comment: Ok, I have copied the complete file here. I executed the command you suggested, and it asked me for my current password then a new one with a confirm too. Is that what I should expect?

Comment: Shouldn't I be able to see Ubuntu in the network section of Windows Explorer? That's what I imagined would happen!

Comment: I have a little trouble getting that to happen regularly for me, but I'm not trying very hard.  And yes - the smbpasswd is separate from your user password, and provides the approval for smb connections.  Is your system operating properly at this time?

Comment: What do you mean, is my system operating properly? Everything seems ok except for these permissions issues.

Comment: One bit at a time?  I did find a fix for network discovery on my Windows machines.  But your question above does not mention a permission issue?

Answer (score 1):

**1st part:** The user that will connect, should have a Samba password on the Ubuntu machine:

You can a smb password for a user defined on your machine with the command

```
sudo smbpasswd -a <username>
```

Replacing `<username>` with the name of the user that will be connecting to a SMB share on your Ubuntu machine.  This user must be aleardy existing user on your machine.

**2nd Part**

It helps to browse the SMB shares if the computers are willing to act as masters for the SMB protocol.  In the [Global] section of the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` add the lines

```
local master = yes
preferred master = yes
```

**3rd part**

Windows now uses WSD (web services discovery?) which is not included in the various Samba's that are available as of Ubuntu 19.04.

There is a project at github which implements WSD, written in Python.  It can be found at https://github.com/christgau/wsdd or directly downloaded at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christgau/wsdd/master/src/wsdd.py

Part of the trick to using this is that you will need to enable a couple of ports through your firewall:

Ports 5357/tcp and 3702/udp need to be open for wsdd to run.

wsdd can be run from the command line, or you could create a systemd service to run it.

This is an active (maybe) area of Samba development, and some information about it can be found at https://www.ixsystems.com/community/resources/how-to-kill-off-smb1-netbios-wins-and-still-have-windows-network-neighbourhood-better-than-ever.106/ and is currently available in the Arch user repository, and apparently a few other distros as well.  It is also mentioned in AskUbuntu at

[make samba share visible in Windows "Network"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661611/make-samba-share-visible-in-windows-network)

**Starting as a service**

I created a systemd service unit file for wsdd as `/lib/systemd/system/wsdd.service`  contents are

```
[Unit]
Description=WSDD Network Service
BindsTo=smbd.service
After=smbd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wsdd
#ExecReload=/user/bin/wsdd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I moved `wsdd.py` to `/usr/bin/wsdd`, and modified its permissions to 555 (read and execute).

Finally, `sudo systemctl enable wsdd.service` and a reboot - and my Ubuntu system is now visible to my Win10 computers.