# Unable to so see or access ubuntu pc in network from Windows

Tags: networking, server, samba

I am having trouble seeing my Ubuntu 18.04 PC (acting as a file and media server) from the windows PCs.
I have installed Samba, Tasksel, System-config-samba, python-glade2, samba-common, smbclient.
Edited avahi-daemon to 0,
Created a "me" and "netguest" users in samba,
sudo ufw allow 'Samba' (even though firewall is disabled),
sudo chmod 777 /media/mydrive/Mystuff (also with all shared folders). Windows PCs are on the Homenet network, Ubuntu PC has a static IP (192.168.0.10) it can be pinged but not accessed or seen.
There are two things that I don't know whether they affect or not, I have 2 routers, the second one is acting as a range extender, but is the only one that can be connected by wire to the Ubuntu PC, the rest are connected via wi-fi. The  smb.conf file is attached. Thank you for any help you may provide.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bdz2RLOqixvrmYVYPV7sHCG2vJIgzQtH

Comment: I went through a lot of this for my home network:  [https://askubuntu.com/a/1142898/283721](https://askubuntu.com/a/1142898/283721)

Comment: Ubuntu recommends rygel for sharing and it works with the sharing section in the config menu. All standard menu driven and works (tested here on 18.4.2-LTS). This is not an answer just a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu PC has a static IP (192.168.0.10) it can be pinged but not
>   accessed or seen.

Please run one of the following commands on your server:

```
nmcli device show | grep DEVICE

ifconfig
```

I would be willing to bet real money that you have no interface named eth0 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Yet that is exactly what you told samba to use with these two lines in smb.conf:

```
interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0
bind interfaces only = yes
```

Remove those two lines so samba can figure it out on its own and restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the 2 lines and finally the server is visible from the other PCs. Probably doe not matter any more but: root@ubuntuserver:/home/mario# nmcli device show | grep DEVICE
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp2s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo